# Inequality of numerical invariants of complex algebraic surfaces?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry

Let $S, T$ be algebraic surfaces over $k=\mathbb{C}$, and $\phi: S \longrightarrow T$ a surjective morphism. Furthermore we have the numerical invariants:
\begin{align*}
q(S) &:= \dim H^1(S, \mathcal{O}_S)\\
P_n &:= \dim H^0(S, nK)
\end{align*}
where $K$ is a canonical divisor.

Now from the literature, i understand that we have
\begin{align*}
q(S) &\geq q(T)\\
P_n(S) &\geq P_n(T)
\end{align*}
which makes intuitively a lot of sense, since i imagine we could somehow pull back elements of the cohomology groups from $T$ to those of $S$.

Could someone explain the principle behind this? It might be really easy; i know just the very basics of sheaf cohomology and am a little stressed for my exam on monday. =)

(By the way, since i mention an exam i feel the need to state: this is not homework)

Thanks!